# Gnuplot, how to generate a 3d point chart

Tags: graph, graphics, 3d, gnuplot

Im using gnuplot and i'm new with it, i want to get a graph with 3d point, my data file is:

```
2195.375 -1824.636 -8.535
2204.789 -1830.72 -798.447
2215.166 -1837.398 -766.727
2226.448 -1844.699 -735.453
2238.655 -1852.604 -704.629 
2251.734 -1861.026 -674.418
2265.695 -1870.098 -644.702
2280.514 -1879.692 -615.603
2296.172 -1889.872 -587.158
2312.677 -1900.587 -559.324
2329.904 -1911.829 -532.302
2347.976 -1923.566 -505.93
2366.791 -1935.812 -480.349
2386.336 -1948.566 -455.535
2406.598 -1961.776 -431.624
2427.574 -1975.432 -408.455
2449.22 -1989.468 -386.209
```

I've tryed with:
    splot 'Escritorio/EtapaRotacion_MEDICIONES.dat'

There is where the data is and i'm getting this error:

```
warning: No usable data in this plot to auto-scale axis range
                                                    ^
All points z value undefined
```

Comment: It is working fine for me.  You may have set an axis range previously.  Try running `reset` before plotting.

Answer (score 1):

You can plot the points with this command:

```
splot "Escritorio/EtapaRotacion_MEDICIONES.dat" with dots
```

You can also use all other gnuplot commands and options to modify the plot; for example

```
splot "Escritorio/EtapaRotacion_MEDICIONES.dat" with dots lc rgb "blue"
```

to plot with blue dots.